# CopyFeatures management creates long name

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, attribute-joins

I'm trying to join a shapefile to a csv file. The join works but the attribute table has the long name of the shapefiles which makes the fields not readable.

How can i fix this problem?

Calling the scrip from an os window as

`C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.4/python csv_2_dbf_tdm.py "D:/01_Inputs/y2035/cube_se2035.csv" "no_bld_tdm_draft1"`

where cube_se2035 is sys.argv[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfuEA.jpg)] and the no_b;dm_tdm_draf1 is a folder name

```
import arcpy
import sys
import os

basename =  os.path.basename(sys.argv[1]).replace(".csv", ".dbf")
dbf_path = sys.argv[1].replace(".csv", ".dbf")
se_shp = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data\se_folder_shapefile\se919.shp")
sys.argv[1] = se_path = "D:/cube_se{year}.csv".format(year=2035)

shapefileName = "temp" 
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(se_shp,shapefileName)

###Join the feature layer to a table
arcpy.AddJoin_management(shapefileName, "DASZ2010",dbf_path, "dasz_id") 

### Copy the layer to a new permanent feature class

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(dd, os.path.join(cube_folder, basename.strip(".dbf")))
```

Here is the table after the join. All the fields have the source name and I just need the field name without the source.

[image]

Comment: Before your `addjoin` command, try adding in this command: `arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False`

Comment: As to your performance problem, try reading your CSV into an in_memory table (Table to Table https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000027000000 should work if you don't want to do the import using primitive read line) then using Join Field https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000 instead of copy features from the joined layer. CSV files are notably clunky and problematic, I would suggest always to convert to a more rigid table format before using, both for performance and error avoidance (trap bad values early).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn off [Qualified Field Names](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/qualified-field-names.htm) before joining.

`arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False`

> Tools that honor the Qualified Field Names environment use this
>   setting to distinguish between qualified or unqualified field names.
>   Qualified field names are the names of fields in a feature class or
>   table that have the name of the origin feature class or table appended
>   onto the field name. This setting is relevant when working with joined
>   data.

Comment: it seems that it should be an argument of the function. Would be easier to know about it.